# Laravel - Using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` with eager-loaded relationship returns wrong count

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

In my Laravel app I was doing an ordinary query on a model (`ModelA`) whilst making use of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and then performing `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` afterwards to retrieve the count of all records since the first query used `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

This worked perfectly fine, but now that I've added a relationship to the model I was querying above, if I do the same query but using `with->('modelB')`, this query is performed after the initial query and before `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` so I get the count of the `ModelB` results instead of `ModelA` as I was expecting.

Is there a way to make this work as desired where I get the count of the first (main) query and not the relationship?

e.g. This works fine:

```
$query = ModelA::select([DB::raw("SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *")])
    ->where('active', 1);

// conditional ->where()'s

$query->skip(intval($skip))
    ->take(intval($take))
    ->orderBy($column, $dir);

$results = $query->get();

$total = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS 'total';"))[0]->total;
```

but changing the first line to this doesn't:

```
$query = ModelA::with('modelB')
    ->select([DB::raw("SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *")])
    ->where('active', 1);
```

A workaround is to just do it without eager-loading and fetch each relationship individually but then I'd have one query per result when I loop through the results later in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The row count available through [`FOUND_ROWS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) is transient and not intended to be available past the statement following the `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` statement. If you need to refer to the value later, save it...

[Eloquent's eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) will cause an extra select statement to be executed for each relationship in the `with` method.

Therefore `FOUND_ROWS()` is returning the count for the last `SELECT` statement, the eagerly loaded relation.

To get around this you can use [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading). Instead of:

```
$books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

Use:

```
$books = App\Book::all();
$count = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()'));
$books->load('author.contacts');
```

Comment: never thought of that, I think that might be the easiest way around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`ModelA::with('modelB')` results in a `join` of the 2 underlying tables. If you have multiple records in `modelB` corresponding to a single record in `modelA`, then the number of records returned by the query may be more, than the number of records in `modelA`. `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` returns the number of records in the overall query, you cannot restrict it to a single table within a query.

Either you count the `modelA` records separately and return that number, or you need to select data in a subquery from modelA's table with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` included in the subquery. I would go for a separate count. It is straightforward and simple.

Comment: I don't think it's doing a join, the `with` seems to be doing a `WHERE IN` to find the records in the other table related to the first. It's a one-to-one if that helps but I was hoping there was maybe some kind of callback or similar to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *` before the second query begins. I think you're right, one query to do a count would be better than one per result without eager-loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) for first relation.

```
$total = 0;

$query = ModelA::with([
    'modelB' => function () use (&$total) {
        $total = (int)DB::select("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as `row_count`")[0]->row_count;
    }
])
->select([DB::raw("SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *")])
->where('active', 1);

$rows = $query->get();

echo $total;
```